# error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

The assignment `C=R.c_str();` in the code below causes G++ to throw the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string R = "killme";
    char *C = new char[100];
    C=R.c_str();
    cout<<*C;
}
```

Why is this an error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The code has two problems. The main one, which causes a compile issue, is the assignment of `c_str()` result, which is `const`, to variable `C`, which is *not* `const`. The compiler tags this as an error, because otherwise you could do this:

```
C=R.c_str();
C[2] = 'c';
```

which would write to a read-only area in memory, causing undefined behavior.

You can fix it in two ways:

- Declare `C` a `const`, i.e. `const char *C = ...`, or
- Copy the content into space that you have allocated.

The first approach is simple - you do this:

```
const char *C = R.c_str();
```

The second approach works like this:

```
char *C = new char[R.size()+1];
std::strcpy(C, R.c_str());
```

The second problem is a memory leak: your code assigns `C` a result of `new`, but never deletes it. If you use `strcpy` approach, you need to add

```
delete[] C;
```

at the end of your program, once you are done using variable `C`.

Comment: Why not simply cast?
e.g. char *c = (char *)myStdStr.c_str();

Comment: @hfrmobile This would work fine for OP's example if you add `const`. However, it wouldn't work in general, because you do not have control over what `c_str()` returns: as soon as you modify the string, or the string goes out of scope, the pointer that you got back from `c_str()` becomes invalid. That's why making a copy provides a safer alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem. See if it works:

```
string R= "killme";

char * cstr = new char [R.length()+1];
strcpy (cstr, R.c_str());
```

You have to include two libraries for this:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<cstring>
```

Answer (score -1):

string::c_str() returns a const char* not a char*. This is the reason of the error.

For more information of the std::string::c_str() see the link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Yes, both the points mentioned above are also correct.